# How to create unique key(keys defined in some list) for dictionary and assign value to it in for loop in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
dct = {}

dct_keys = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

city_list = ['Pune', 'Delhi', 'Ahmedabad', 'Mumbai']

for city in city_list:
  dct[key from dct_keys] = city
```

Note: length of "city_list" is equal to or less than "dct_keys"

I want to create a dictionary with my defined keys(stored in some list) and assign value to them using for loop.

How to do this ?

Comment: naive solution: index variable, increment.

Comment: What is 'name'? And you aren't even using 'city'.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, may be `dict(zip(dct_keys, city_list))`.

Comment: What is the expected output when length of `city_list` is less than `dct_keys`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the values yet:

```
>>> dct_keys = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
>>> dict1 = dict.fromkeys(dct_keys)
>>> print dict1
{'four': None, 'three': None, 'two': None, 'one': None}
```

If you have the values already:

```
>>> dct_vals = [1,2,3,4]
>>> dict2 = dict(zip(dct_keys, dct_vals))
>>> print dict2
{'four': 4, 'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

Using a dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in zip(dct_keys, city_list)}
{'four': 'Mumbai', 'one': 'Pune', 'three': 'Ahmedabad', 'two': 'Delhi'}
```

Comment: On python2 consider using `itertools.izip` to avoid building a useless list of 2-element tuples.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
for i in xrange(len(city_list)):
    dct[dct_keys[i]] = city_list[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over multiple lists.

```
for key, city in zip(dct_keys, city_list):
  dct[key] = city
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this in one statement:

```
dict1 = dict(zip(dct_keys, city_list))
```